# How to call subroutine in perl according to user input(string)?

Tags: perl, if-statement, user-input, subroutine

I am new in perl programming and I am trying to call subroutines with respect to user input:

```
print "Would you like to [A]dd a new student or [R]eturn to the previous menu?";
    $tempCommand = <>;
    if($tempCommand eq "A") {addStudent()}
    elsif($tempCommand eq "R") {mainmenu()}
    else{mainmenu()}
```

The call always end up on the else condition even if 
I enter A or R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to chomp the newline from your user input and it should work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;


print "Would you like to [A]dd a new student or [R]eturn to the previous menu? ";

chomp(my $tempCommand = <>);

if ($tempCommand eq "A") {
  addStudent()
}

elsif ($tempCommand eq "R") {
  mainmenu()
}

else {
  mainmenu()
}


sub addStudent {
  print "In sub \"Addstudent\"";
}

sub mainmenu {
  print "In sub \"Mainmenu\"";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that when you read from `STDIN` using `<>`, the value you get back and store in `$tempCommand` will have a newline character attached to it. You need to remove that with the `chomp()` function.

```
chomp($tempCommand = <>);
```